# can you index characters from a UITableView section and use it as an alias to give an expanded name to Section?

Tags: xcode5, alias, uitableview

I have a UITableView that lists reports from a website. These reports are from an existing database and I am not able to change the names they already have.

All of the report names start with the appropriate word to describe the reports type. i.e. POT, CA, Annual, Audit etc.

I have indexed the first 3 characters from these report names to section the reports into the appropriate sections, but this means that the section names are POT, Ann, CA , Aud etc. What I would like to do is take those indexed characters and use them as an alias to expand the names to their full names.

Can this be done easily?

EDIT TO SHOW WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED

I tried to set defines for the 3 letter indexed values, in the hope that they would change based on that information, but this did not work.

Does anyone have any ideas that could help me. I am more than happy to completely change my approach if there is another way to make it work. Maybe there is a way to remove numbers from values??

CURRENT CODE FOR UITABLEVIEW

```
#import "reportsTestViewController.h"
#import "ReportsDataObject.h"
#import "Session.h"

@interface reportsTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation reportsTestViewController

@synthesize response;

@synthesize myDataIvar;


#define POT "PATH OF TRAVEL"
#define Ann "ANNUAL PASSIVE"
#define Aud "AUDIT"
#define CA "CONTRACTOR AUDIT"


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    reportsTable.delegate = self;
    reportsTable.dataSource = self;
    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
//    

    //Create your request pointing to the test page
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tesg.com.au/allCustBuild.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //initialize it when you create your connection
    if (connection){
        self.myDataIvar = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        [self.myDataIvar setLength:0];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
        [self.myDataIvar appendData:data];

    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed: %@", error.userInfo);
    }

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //this is where you would parse the data received back from the server
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.myDataIvar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received Data: %@",responseString);
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:self.myDataIvar];

}

-(void)connectionWasASuccess:(NSData *)data{
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:data];

}



-(void)setupReportsFromJSONArray:(NSData*)dataFromReportsArray{
    BOOL found;
    NSError *error;
   // NSMutableArray *reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromReportsArray options:0 error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"error parsing the json data from server with error description - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    else {
        reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
        {

            ReportsDataObject *report = [[ReportsDataObject alloc] initWithJSONData:eachReport];

            [reportsArray addObject:report];
            NSString *c = [[eachReport objectForKey:@"title"] substringToIndex:3];
                      found = NO;

            for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToString:c])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
            }
        }

        }
        NSLog(@"Array Populated");
        NSLog(@"%u reports found",reportsArray.count);
        //Now you have your reportsArray filled up with all your data objects



for (NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
{
   [[self.sections objectForKey:[[eachReport objectForKey:@"title"] substringToIndex:3]] addObject:eachReport];
}

// Sort each section array
for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]]];


}

[reportsTable reloadData];
}


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSUInteger count = [[self.sections allKeys] count];
    NSLog(@"Number of sections: %d", count);
    return count;
}




- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    {
        NSUInteger count = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
        NSLog(@"Number of rows in section: %d", count);
        return count;
    }
}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }





-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

        //The beauty of this is that you have all your data in one object and grab WHATEVER you like
    //This way in the future you can add another field without doing much.
    NSUInteger count = [[self.sections allKeys] count];
    if(count == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"no reports to show";
    }
    else{
        NSDictionary *Reports = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [Reports objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [Reports objectForKey:@"building"];



        // in the future you can grab whatever data you need like this
        //[currentReport buildingName], or [currentReport reportName];
    }


    return(cell);


    }





@end
```

Comment: No-one able to help??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alias and even less sure how you intend to use the "full names" but my first thought is that this sounds like a job for a NSDictionary with the short names as keys and the full names as values.

Comment: thanks for the reply Phillip To give you a brief and very simple example, POT is an acronym for Path Of Travel. All of these reports start with POT and include a year, however, some also include other information. I have indexed the first 3 characters of each report name (3 characters is the most I can index and still guarantee naming integrity) and I am using these indexed characters to separate the reports into appropriate sections in a UITableView. This means that the sections are named with the 3 indexed characters i got from the name.

Comment: I want to programmatically change the name from POT to Path Of Travel for the POT section, Audit for the aud section Annual Passive for the ann section etc

Comment: That still sounds like a NSDictionary.  Assuming your data source implements `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`, it could use a dictionary to look up the equivalent of "POT" (etc.) and return an array of those strings.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I'll look into doing that. You should add an answer so I can accept it :-)

Comment: Maybe...if it works...let me know. :)  (Without code, I'm still not convinced I understand you exactly.)

Comment: i have added my current code so you can see what I am doing. That code populates the array correctly, shows the UITableView with a sorted list of all of the reports that are downloadable. It then sections those reports using the indexed characters from the 'title' field. This separates them very well and allows all reports of the same type to be grouped together, however, the names of the sections are the problem as they are named with those 3 indexed characters.

Comment: Awwww i'm stuck on this one, I can't figure out how to integrate the dictionary into the current code. do you have an example or some information I could look at to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think you want something like this:

Create a `NSDictionary` property called `titleReference`.
Initialize it when you first create your controller

```
self.titleReference = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"PATH OF TRAVEL", @"POT",
                       @"ANNUAL PASSIVE", @"Ann",
                       @"AUDIT", @"Aud",
                       @"CONTRACTOR AUDIT", @"CA",
                       nil];
```

Use it to populate an array that matches the one you've created.

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray *keys = [[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[keys count]];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSString *title = [self.titleReference objectForKey:key];
        if (title) {
            [titles addObject:title];
        } else {
            [titles addObject:key];
        }
    }
    return titles;
}
```

Comment: man that is SO CLOSE but its not quite there. That code gave me the full names (Awesome coz that means the dictionary works!!) but it puts the names in the index at the right hand side of the screen. I don't wanna have that index, just the section names. I tried to substitute sectionIndexTitlesForTableView for titleForHeaderInSection but it didnt work. I'm assuming the code needs some tweaking. Can you use the dictionary and array for titleForHeaderInSection?

Comment: See…I told you I didn't quite understand what you needed.  :)  But, yes, in your `titleForHeaderInSection` method use the string you're currently returning as the key into the dictionary and return the matching title.

Comment: Hi Phillip, I have been trying this all morning and I have hit brick walls all the way through. I don't know how to use the returned string as "a key into the dictionary" I keep getting incompatible pointer types errors and I am not sure how the syntax works. Can you please do me a favour and show me a non specific example, so I can learn how it works?

Comment: Hi Phillip, I am still stuck with this one. are you able to show me an example of how to use a dictionary for the section names, without having the index at the right of the screen?

Comment: If you use the same dictionary, wouldn't it just be: `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
return [self.titleReference objectForKey:key];
}`  …and revert back to your original code for the section index titles?

Comment: DUDE you're a life saver!! I had that backwards! I was trying to call titleReference in NSString and i kept getting errors. Thank you very much for your help!!